# GNU make: include file only if target is not "clean"

Tags: gnu-make

Using GNU make, I want to include a file, *except* if the current target is "clean".

That is, I want to do the equivalent of the following:

```
ifneq($(TARGET),clean)
-include somefile.txt
endif
```

But for that, I need a variable whose value is the target given on the command line (here named $(TARGET)). Such a variable does not seem to exist, and I can understand why, because you could have multiple targets on the command line, some of which you might want to include the file for, and others not. Actually, it would be fine if the file is included when there are other targets besides "clean". The only real problem I currently have is that when the file to be included does not exist, Make will try to build it, which is unnecessary when you're about to delete it again when executing the "clean" target.

So, is there another way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`MAKECMDGOALS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html).  Use it like this to handle multiple arguments on the command line:

```
ifeq (clean,$(filter clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
-include somefile.txt
endif
```

However, this is often fraught because if you run `make clean all` or whatever, the include file won't be included even though it might be needed for `all`.

If you really need this to be reliable another way is to use recursion for your "top-level" arguments, running them one at a time in a sub-make.

Comment: Thanks. MAKECMDGOALS is not listed in the list of special variables in the make documentation, probably they hid it deliberately since it's only for "special circumstances". And it's nice that the first example they give for "appropriate use" is basically the same as my case. It's not terribly important that this is 100% reliable, although it looks like I can use $(filter-out ...) to make it (nearly) so.

Comment: I tried playing with  ifneq (,$(filter-out clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS))) , but couldn't get that to do the right thing either, so I settled on a simple ifneq (clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS)) which seems to cover all common cases well.

Comment: I don't know why you keep trying to use `filter-out`, when I wrote `filter` above.  Indeed, it will be difficult to use `filter-out` for this test.  It will return all the words in the list that do _not_ match `clean` which is not so helpful here.  You'd have to do something like `ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),$(filter-out clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))`

Comment: The idea was that I wanted to include the file if there is _any_ other target than `clean`, which is exactly what my `filter-out` test does. However, that doesn't work when there is no target at all (i.e., the default target will be built). So then I realized that what I want is actually to only skip including the file if `clean` is the one and only target, which is what the simple `ifneq` test of my May 21 comment does.

Answer (score 1):

You could usefully check that if clean is a target then it is the only target. Otherwise strange things can go wrong silently causing much wailing and gnashing of teeth. My most recent Makefile includes the following. (NB tested but not as yet used extensively).

```
ifeq (clean,$(filter clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
ifneq($(strip $(filter-out clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
$(error ERROR: can not make other targets with clean
endif
endif
```